# Using {tabu} to make thick table lines in header generates errors

Tags: errors, header-footer, tabu

I want to place a thick vertical line next to my page number in the header of every page. I have chosen to build a small table and add the line to it. It works fine, until I add the option (part of the `{tabu}` package) of defining the thickness of the table border. The code (that generates many errors) looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%no top ruler
\fancyheadoffset{0.8 cm}
\fancyhead[RO]{\begin{tabu}{|[2pt]c}\bfseries\thepage \\ ~ \end{tabu}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\begin{tabu}{c|[2pt]}\bfseries\thepage \\ ~ \end{tabu}}
\headheight=24pt
~
\newpage
~
\end{document}
```

when I put the table in the main text (i.e. not in the header) they come out fine

```
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt]c}\bfseries\thepage \\ ~ \end{tabu}
```

when I remove the `[2pt]` line there is no problem either.
Nevertheless, I can't make out from the generated errors what went wrong. For instance, the first error reads:

```
!missing number, treated as zero
```

When I compile this as part of my larger project, the compilation process crashes entirely!

My questions would be: Why is this code not working inside of headers and how should it be changed to obtain the desired effect?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Unfortunately the `tabu` package is often incompatible with latex (most notably in its unfortunate decisions to change the `>` syntax, here it is tripping over active characters.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabu}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%no top ruler
\fancyheadoffset{0.8 cm}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[RO]{\let\@activechar@info\@gobble\begin{tabu}{|[2pt]c}\bfseries\thepage \tabularnewline ~ \end{tabu}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\let\@activechar@info\@gobble\begin{tabu}{c|[2pt]}\bfseries\thepage \tabularnewline ~ \end{tabu}}
\makeatother
\headheight=24pt
\begin{document}
~ 
\newpage
~
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this indeed works splendidly! Do I understand correctly that the code you have added finds and suppresses the use of any active characters by the `{tabu}` package?

Comment: @skleijn the description you give makes it sound like a rather grander project than  it was:-): better to say it is a workaround that locally disables some code in the standard output routine to avoid the particular error that your example showed. all `\@activechar@info` does is make a warning that active characters are being used in an unsafe place, but the warning itself messes up tabu's processing of the array preamble so I silence the warning.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a sledgehammer. Better measurement can be obtained by using rules and doing carefully the alignment.

Here's a possibility (the `showframe` option and the `geometry` package are used just for the example):

```
\documentclass{book}

%% the following two packages are just for the example
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%no top ruler
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightpage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftpage}

\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}

\newcommand{\digitheight}{\fontcharht\font`0 }
\newcommand{\rightpage}{\mypagenumber{\ }{l}{\ \ \bfseries\thepage}}
\newcommand{\leftpage}{\mypagenumber{\bfseries\thepage\ \ }{r}{\ }}
% Arguments of \mypagenumber:
% #1: tokens to be set at the left of the bar
% #2: position of the bar (use l for the right header, r for the left)
% #3: tokens to be set at the right of the bar
\newcommand{\mypagenumber}[3]{%
  \raisebox{\ht\strutbox-\digitheight}{%
    \makebox[0pt][#2]{%
      \bfseries
      #1%
      \vrule depth \dimexpr 24pt - \digitheight\relax width 2pt
      #3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

### Page 1

[image]

### Page 2

[image]

### Page 1 without frames

[image]